# Libtool Version mismatch error while building gcc

Tags: gcc, open-source, autotools, libtool

I am trying to add some files to GCC source code, but after running
`autoreconf --install --force`
i get that error

```
libtool: definition of this LT_INIT comes from libtool 2.2.7a.
libtool: You should recreate aclocal.m4 with macros from libtool 2.4.6 Debian-2.4.6-14
libtool: and run autoconf again.
```

even without any source files added if i reconfigure i get the same error.

that's very important as i am adding new functionality to gcc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `autoreconf --install --force` instead of just `autoreconf` is a bit questionable in this case, but maybe it's for the best.  I am surprised that it did not take care of `aclocal.m4` for you automatically, but that's a generated file.  If everything else is ok then you ought to be able to simply delete the current `aclocal.m4` and run `autoreconf` to generate a new one.

If you have an `autom4te.cache` subdirectory then it would probably be best to delete that first (it will be regenerated by `autoreconf`, too).